# Why I get; initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char *' discards qualifiers?

Tags: c

I can't figure out why I get this warning from `clang` by myself:

```
function_prototype_const_modifier.c:13:8: warning: initializing 'char *' with an
      expression of type 'const char *' discards qualifiers
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        char *ptr1 = source;
              ^      ~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

The code is very simple

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *my_strcpy(char *destination, const char *source);

int main(void) {
    char str1[] = "this is something";  
    char str2[] = "123456789123456789";
    my_strcpy(str2, str1);
    puts(str2);
    return 0;
}
char *my_strcpy(char *destination, const char *source) {
    char *ptr1 = source;
    char *ptr2 = destination;
    while(*ptr1 != '\0') {
        *ptr2++ = *ptr1++;
    }
    *ptr2 = '\0';
    return destination;
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`source` is a `const char *`, a pointer to const characters, so the characters cannot be changed by dereferencing the pointer (i. e. `source[0] = 'A';` is a constraint violation).

However, assigning it to a `char *` *discards* this constraint; a simple `char *` suggests that the characters pointed to by the `ptr1` pointer are not constant and you can now freely write `ptr1[0] = 'A';` without getting compiler errors (a "diagnostic message").

Consider what this means when you pass in a string literal. Since a string literal is "readonly" (it's a `const char []`), trying to modify its contents is undefined behavior. So if you call

```
my_strcpy(destination, "Constant String");
```

but in the code for some reason you write

```
ptr1[0] = 'A';
```

you won't get a compiler diagnostic message because `ptr1` is a pointer to non-const chars, but your program will still invoke undefined behavior (and in practice, most likely crash, since string literals are placed in readonly memory regions).

Answer (score 10):

You just need to change:

```
char *ptr1 = source;
```

to:

```
const char *ptr1 = source;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are pointing to the same area in memory, but not qualifying it as `const` as well, which the argument is.

You then allow the function body to modify that part of memory which is labelled `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Because type of L.H.S is `char *` and type of R.H.S is `const char *`.

The reason is exactly as what error says:

> function_prototype_const_modifier.c:13:8: warning: initializing 'char *' with an       expression of type 'const char *' discards qualifiers

The statement allows you to discard the `const` qualifier and it allows to modify the pointed string through `ptr1` and `ptr2` and hence the compiler complains.

Comment: I would think `const` meant the _pointer_ was constant and not the pointee. I would be mistaken.

Comment: Jan read it right to left (helps me anyway). pointer to a character constant. 
char const * is a pointer constant to a character.

Comment: @JanDvorak the `const` keyword applies to the term on its right, if there's no term on its right, only then applies the `const` keyword to the term on its left.

Comment: @H2CO3 agreed. And the term on its right is `char *`, a char pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a pointer to a character constant to a pointer to a char. 
By doing that you risk **modifying the character(s)**.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, just about what's we can do.

Thanks of clearness information for @user529758.

Just plus a answer.

Modified:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *my_strcpy(char *destination, const char *source);

int main(void) {
    char str1[] = "this is something";  
    char str2[] = "123456789123456789";
    my_strcpy(str2, str1);
    puts(str2);
    return 0;
}
char *my_strcpy(char *destination, const char *source) {
    char *ptr1 = (char*)source;
    char *ptr2 = destination;
    while(*ptr1 != '\0') {
        *ptr2++ = *ptr1++;
    }
    *ptr2 = '\0';
    return destination;
}
```