# Char *string [] declaration error

Tags: c, pointers, char

What is wrong with this declaration?

```
char *add_element[] = {"1","S"};
```

I get this error when I compile this -

```
warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

What am I doing wrong?

This question is different from [Why I get; initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char *' discards qualifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005762/why-i-get-initializing-char-with-an-expression-of-type-const-char-disca). This can be verified by comment written below. Thanks for answering it.

The possible duplicate question is related, but not the same. It is about why void func(const char *ptr) { char *local = ptr; ... } elicits the warning, rather than dealing with an initializer as here. I don't think this question should be closed as a duplicate of that question

Comment: More often than not, searching Stack Overflow for the error message gets you a good answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm going to print that comment of yours and put it in a golden frame.

Comment: The possible duplicate question is related, but not the same.  It is about why `void func(const char *ptr) { char *local = ptr; ... }` elicits the warning, rather than dealing with an initializer as here.  I don't think this question should be closed as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: What compiler/environment?  Can you show us your command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You appear to be using GCC and have `-Write-strings` turned on.  That makes the compiler warn about exactly this situation.  It makes the string literals into `const char` arrays rather than `char` arrays, making your initialization discard the `const`.  Use:

```
const char *add_element[] = { "1", "S" };
```

Or turn off `-Wwrite-strings`.

From the GCC manual:

> **`-Wwrite-strings`**
>
> When compiling C, give string constants the type **`const char[length]`** so that
>              copying the address of one into a non-`const` **`char *`** pointer will get a
>              warning.  These warnings will help you find at compile time code that can try
>              to write into a string constant, but only if you have been very careful about
>              using `const` in declarations and prototypes.  Otherwise, it will just be a
>              nuisance. This is why we did not make **`-Wall`** request these warnings.
>
> When compiling C++, warn about the deprecated conversion from string literals
>              to **`char *`**.  This warning is enabled by default for C++ programs.

Comment: Somebody here on SO told me that string literals are `char[]` for historical reasons. Now what?

Comment: @JanDvorak `const char *add_element[]`.

Comment: @H2CO3, that's true.  They just decay into pointers in the initialization.  I could clarify, I guess, but that's a pretty subtle point for a beginner.

Comment: However, even I answered that it's `const char *`. I'm really confused.

Comment: this question is tagged C and string literals in C are not `const char[N]` but `char[N]`.

Comment: @ouah, in this case the OP must have something (compiler? flag?) that make them `const`, or he wouldn't get that warning.

Comment: Some googling seems to indicate older G++, maybe?  I'll update my answer in a bit.

Comment: @CarlNorum my guess is also that the compiler is a C++ compiler or that the error does not come from this line. You cannot make string literals `const char[N]` without breaking a lot of things.

Comment: Found it: `-Wwrite-strings` to gcc generates this message.

Comment: And clang will warn when given that flag too, but gives a more verbose message.